# Passing value to ObjectParameter variables

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure with some parameters. These are my parameters for my procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SaveInvitation]
(
    @InvitationID INT OUTPUT,
    @UserID INT,
    @Email NCHAR(100),
    @InvitationGUID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
```

My `function.cs`:

```
public SaveInvitation_Result SaveInvitation(int userID,string email)
{
        SaveInvitation_Result result = null;

        var results = this.DataContext.SaveInvitation(null,userID,email,null);

        if (results != null)
        {
            result = results.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I am passing some parameters to my function `SaveInvitation` like this:

My `DataBaseModel.Designer.cs`:

```
public ObjectResult<SaveInvitation_Result> SaveInvitation(ObjectParameter invitationID, Nullable<global::System.Int32> userID, global::System.String email, ObjectParameter invitationGUID)
{
        ObjectParameter userIDParameter;
        if (userID.HasValue)
        {
            userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID);
        }
        else
        {
            userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        }

        ObjectParameter emailParameter;
        if (email != null)
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", email);
        }
        else
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<SaveInvitation_Result>("SaveInvitation", invitationID, userIDParameter, emailParameter, invitationGUID);
}
```

When I execute this function/procedure I get an exception

> *The parameter at index 0 in the parameters array is null.*

How can I pass values to `invitationID` and `invitationGUID`?

Comment: Have you initialized those parameters before calling SaveInvitation?

Comment: @JleruOHeP Thank  you for reply  I am not able to initialize it. How can I initialize? I have passed null value when I am calling SaveInvitation.

Comment: with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb301079.aspx, like ObjectParameter invitationID = new ObjectParameter("InvitationID", typeof(int));

Comment: How can I use this in My Funcation.cs

Comment: If you wont use those parameters anyway, you can remove them from parameters of SaveInvitation and instead pass new ObjectParameters into ExecuteFunction<SaveInvitation_Result>

Comment: pls see the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517956/is-it-possible-to-use-output-parameters-with-executequeryt


i think .. u can use the 'ref'

Comment: Word of advice: I would *not* make a longer string `nchar(100)`  - this will **always** use 100 characters with 2 bytes each - even if your `email` is just 5 characters long. Instead: use `nvarchar(100)` for variable length strings!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9):

When `userID` or `email` is `null`, you must set the value of the parameter to `DBNull.Value`:

```cs
public ObjectResult<SaveInvitation_Result> SaveInvitation(ObjectParameter invitationID, Nullable<global::System.Int32> userID, global::System.String email, ObjectParameter invitationGUID)
{
    ObjectParameter userIDParameter;
    if (userID.HasValue)
    {
        userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID);
    }
    else
    {
        userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        userIDParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }

    ObjectParameter emailParameter;
    if (email != null)
    {
        emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", email);
    }
    else
    {
        emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(global::System.String));
        emailParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }

    return base.ExecuteFunction<SaveInvitation_Result>("SaveInvitation", invitationID, userIDParameter, emailParameter, invitationGUID);
}
```

Comment: I have passed valued to email,userid.

Comment: Not that I added the lines `userIDParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;` and `emailParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;`.  These are necessary to set the parameter's value to the database representation of `NULL`.  Otherwise the parameter is left in an uninitialized state.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just a comment instead of typeof(global::System.Int32)   typeof(int) is also fine